# How to move one word left in the vi editor

Tags: vim, vi

I use the shortcut <kbd>w</kbd> to move the cursor one word right. Is there a shortcut to move a word left?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that this site is intended for questions directly related to programming problems; questions "how to *use* software X" would be better answered at superuser.com . I have voted to close this question; it would be automatically migrated there.

Comment: Your post is still confusing, `w` does not move the cursor left. What are you trying to achieve? Moving the cursor (and if so in what direction) or moving words (again in what direction).

Comment: @Suresh: In future, try ask Vim-related questions on: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ If they are not Windows-specific, it won't be offtopic there, and you might find better answers then on SU, or at least faster

Comment: @Goran Jovic , I moved to SU for these kind of questions, thanks.

Comment: @Suresh: Ok, I'm just saying there's a Unix.SE as well :)

Comment: Please. Stop scattering the vim community on all SE forums. We have 2707 questions tagged vim here on SO, 484 on SU, and now we have 31 question tagged vim on this new SE forum. BTW: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-are-the-best-general-purpose-programming-tools-to-complement-vim is completely off-topic there as SO is meant to be programming centred. (BTW I do use vim on windows every day.)

Comment: @Luc: I have asked vim questions here myself and (as a child with a new toy) I find it very convenient to scroll through the new questions daily. On what site would you prefer vim specific questions being asked?

Comment: @Lieven : Consensus seems to be 'keep Vim questions on SO' since answers often includes vimscripts and Vim is a 'code oriented' tool. See question on Meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/154445

Comment: I'd also vote for here (SO) (or even better: directly on vim mailing list)

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Use <kbd>b</kbd> to move back one word.

Use <kbd>w</kbd> to move forward one word.

And here is a cheat sheet that might be useful for you:

[image]

Source: *[Graphical vi-vim Cheat Sheet and Tutorial](http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html)*

Answer (score 26):

It's <kbd>b</kbd>.

You can see other motions here:

*[Vim documentation: motion, 4. Word motions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#word-motions)*

Generally a Vim command consists of:

*count action motion*

Where:

*count* is number of times you want it to execute. The default is 1.

*action* is obviously an action: <kbd>d</kbd> for delete, <kbd>c</kbd> for change, default is empty, and it means simply move.

*motion* is the direction. You got that already.

Comment: I think what the OP is after is a shortcut to move a word to the right (or left, the title is confusing) not the cursor.

Comment: @Peter: the question says he uses `w` to move left, so apparently he's just trying to move the cursor

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: The OP has edited the question. In it's present form it's clear that @Goran Jovic's answer is indeed what the OP was after. I will upvote the answer.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the <kbd>b</kbd> movement mentioned in the other answers, another movement which may be interesting is <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

It brings you to the last letter of the word on the left. When <kbd>b</kbd> is considered as the opposite of <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> can be considered as the opposite of <kbd>e</kbd> which brings you to the end of the current word.

Also note that all of those word-wise movement have a WORD-wise equivalent: <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> which are "faster". For the difference between words and WORDS see: [`:h word`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#word).

Comment: // , Do you have a reference or something for those of us who want to try this out?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "a reference". If you want to try these motions you can just open a file in vim and try the motions, right?

Comment: Thanks so much for this, was looking for a way to have that functionality. Navigating backwards by end-of-words is much better IMO.

Comment: Oh, and one can do `4ge` to move 4 words here as well etc.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use "b" to backforward a word, and in advance, "2b" to move back two words.

Comment: What do you mean by *"backforward"*? Do you mean *"go backwards"*? Or *"move backwards"*? Or something else?

Answer (score 5):

You want to move left (back). `b` does it.