# In Vim, I'd like to go back a word. The opposite of `w`

Tags: vim

When you're using vim, you can move forward word by word with `w`. How do I go backwards?

Comment: http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif  

This has a lot of the vim keys in an easy graphical format. I highly recommend printing it and having it next to your computer if you are going to be using vim a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move one word left in vi editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488979/how-to-move-one-word-left-in-vi-editor)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125270/in-vim-vi-how-do-you-move-the-cursor-to-the-end-of-the-previous-word if interested in going backwards to the end of previous word - using ge and gE

Answer (score 347, accepted):

Use `b` to go back a word.

You may also want to check out `W` and `B` to advance/go back a `WORD` (which 
consists of a sequence of non-blank characters separated with white space, according to `:h WORD`).

Comment: For completeness sake `ge` will go backward to the end of a word. `gE` will go backward to the end of a `WORD`

Comment: @Peter Rincker: and `e` and `E` will go forward.

Comment: What's the difference between b and B?  Or w and W?  Behavior seems the same.

Comment: @CaseyPatton: The uppercase versions treat any sequence of non-whitespace as words; lowercase is similar to `\w|\S`. See `:help word` and `:help WORD` for more details.

Comment: Also worth considering ge and gE for going backwards to the end of the previous word. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125270/in-vim-vi-how-do-you-move-the-cursor-to-the-end-of-the-previous-word

Comment: `ge` is the correct answer here, not `b` or `W` or `B`

Answer (score 110):

It helps for me to think of it as:

`b` to go to beginning of current or previous word

`w` to go the beginning of next word

`e` to go to the end of current or next word

`ge` to go the end of the previous word

Try `:h word-motions` for more details and how to combine them with operations.

Answer (score 10):

use "b" to move back - just tested in vi - works fine.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, if you use `w`, `b`, `W`, and `B` to navigate lines by hopping over words, consider the following alternatives which can be faster if used correctly.

```
f<char>    # jump to next occurrence of <char> to right (inclusive)
```

or

```
F<char>    # jump back to next occurrence of <char> to left (inclusive)
```

## If your words are separated by spaces

If your words are separated by `<space>` you can hop over words by spaces:

`f<space>;;;;` where `;` repeats the previous command, so you hop forward by spaces

`F<space>;;` to hop backwards by space

## If your words are separated by punctuation and not spaces

just replace `<char>` with punctuation, for example `.`

The punctuation method is not efficient for scrolling through, but if you know where you want to jump, it can usually get there in a jump or two.